# How get permission on WatchFace

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I have a application on Android Wear. App comprises only WatchFace.
How I can get permission without activity?
Permission added into manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a little `Activity` solely for this purpose.

- Start it from your `WatchFaceService` (before trying to use the permission)
- Call `requestPermissions()` in its `onCreate()` method
- In `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, communicate the result back to your `WatchFaceService`, then call `finish()`

To keep this activity from being visible to the user while it does these things, declare it in your manifest as such:

```
    <activity android:name="com.mypackage.PermissionRequestor"
              android:theme="@style/NoDisplay"
        />
```

There's a bit more work if you're also going to support rationales, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Permissions -> Select your app -> Turn on the permissions you have put in your manifest file